# Is it possible to add dnn: META dynamically?

Tags: themes, dotnetnuke

How to add a Meta viewport base on user configuration on my Dnn theme?
Like:

if current user has MetaViewPort active
then add

```
<dnn:META ID="mobileScale" runat="server" Name="viewport" Content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do or what the problem could be of having that meta always present. But it has a `Visible` property, so maybe you can control that. If not it is best to create a SkinObject yourself.

Comment: We have been using that meta for responsive abilities on our theme. The problem is that several users like the site without that meta (non-responsive desing).

Comment: Then I think a SkinObject is the easiest. It can access the DNN object like `UserInfo` and show/hide the meta based on that. Or don't use the dnn:meta object at all but create it with an `HtmlMeta` object added to the `Page` object.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can add a Meta Tag programatically, either from a Module or a SkinObject. Note that this is not DNN specific, it will work for all aspnet websites.

```
HtmlMeta hm = new HtmlMeta();
hm.Attributes.Add("name", "viewport");
hm.Content = "width=device-width,initial-scale=1";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(hm);

//or if you do not have direct access to the Page object
Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
page.Header.Controls.Add(hm);
```